# Meta-Privileges Oddity

Tags: discussion, meta, privileges

So on the [Meta Privileges Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), I see:
[image: privileges]

Yet, I was unable to find the normal review button, so I clicked on [Access Review Queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), it says that:

> Note: These two queues do not exist on per-site Metas.

**So, my question is why is this even listed as an achievement?**

Comment: @Mat That does indeed seem to be a duplicate.  I did not see that when I searched.  Nonetheless, it was not answered.  It's not too big of a deal, but it's very "Misleading."

Comment: @Downvoter, I voted to close and you still downvote me?

Comment: People downvote for lots of different reasons on Meta (perhaps someone   doesn't think this is worth addressing at all). One thing you should _not_ do is complain about downvotes. That will, quite often, result in more of those.